# Naming objects the same, but in different namespaces

Tags: php, laravel, oop, namespaces

In the system, we have settings for users and the system itself. Typically, I might name their controllers and other objects something like `SystemSettingsController` and `UserSettingsController`. I'm separating the controllers though into their own folders and so they have different namespaces.

Has anyone considered the object's namespace in naming the object and is that proper usage of it? I'm thinking of doing something like `users\SettingsController` and `system\SettingsController` instead. So they have the same name, but the differences can be distinguished by their namespaces.

Comment: This more a matter of taste, how much file you like to work with by folder and time you can loost with your IDE autocompletion (it's boring if you have 10 classes same name). As for me i prefer to set functionnal folders, in your case i would have done Controller/UserSettingsController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

```
use Carrington/User/SettingsController as UserSettingsController;
use Carrington/System/SettingsController as SystemSettingsController;
```

To separate the classes from each other

Comment: Definitely. If I were to use both in the same class, then I would alias them. But from what I see, you would find it acceptable to do the same thing as I mentioned, in which they're both called `SettingsController` right?

Comment: @kenshin9 Yes, it's more then just acceptable, that's why namespaces are used for. Don't try to name the class by its complete function, categorize it. When aliasing, you can alias the hell out of it, it doesn't affect the class. If both classss do basically he same thing for each _category_, you can structure the classes by for example inheriting a base class like _utility/AbstractSettingsController_. Or if your rule of thumb is that the _utility_ category only contains abstract classes/interfaces, just call it _utility/SettingsController_ the same way.